# How to filter options in a select element based on taxonomy?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, forms

I have a taxonomy (Bioregions) of regions in our country. It has a few extensions which are used in different contexts (A user may come from "outside NZ", an event may be "nationwide" or "online"). We achieved this by creating a second taxonomy, bioregion_use (terms of user, event), which has been applied as a field on Bioregions. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217817/disable-taxonomy-terms-in-certain-contexts-or-split-into-different-vocabularies/217827?noredirect=1#comment266206_217827) for details.
So now I am wondering how to use this to filter out the  elements which are not wanted in the context of the form being used (create/edit user vs create/edit event).
I've gotten as far as guessing it might involve hook_form_alter()

Edit: The filtering to options only tagged with "event" will be needed in several forms, e.g. create/edit event plus exposed filters on views-generated pages - so is there a way to avoid creating a separate function for each form where this occurs?